# update 100 million records in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert, data-warehouse

I have source and target table containing 100 columns and 100 million of records each. Now my source table got updated with extra 5 columns i.e. now my source table is having 105 columns and 100 millions of records.

I want to update my target table with the extra 5 columns and update the data as well added in the source table.how can i do it with the best optimized approach ?(may be something like update and insert)

The source and target table is having one to one mapping of columns. there is no  transformation happening from source to target table.The source table is truncate load so there might be case of new records added or some records present in target but not in source.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b7p7.png)

Comment: I doubt it's possible to answer this question without knowing the specifics on how exactly the target table is built off of the source table, and the relationships between the tables.

Comment: @rajat added more detail Hope it helps

Comment: Should source and target contain the same data?